# number of threads per flink task manager

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam, flink-streaming, apache-beam-io

I am using a flink task manager with 5-6 pipelines. When the task manager reaches the number of threads to 900+ I am seeing performance issues where the pipeline gets stuck while cancelling, restarting, redeploying the pipeline. When the thread count is less than 800 I don't see this problem.

1. is there a limit on number of threads
2. what is relation with number of tasks in pipeline to number of threads